# How to pass a pointer variable as a reference parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

When you have a function like this, the formal parameter is a reference, it becomes another name for the actual argument, so that when we modify the formal parameter inside the function, the original variable outside the function is changed.

```
void add_five(int& a)
{
    a += 5;
}

int main()
{
    int number = 3;
    add_five(number);
    std::cout << number << std::endl;  // prints 8

    return 0;
}
```

I have some code which works on a linked lists. And I am passing two `Node*`s into the function.

```
void LinkedList::move_five_nodes(Node* ptr1, Node* ptr2) { ... }

...

void LinkedList::anotherFunction()
{
    Node* leader;
    Node* trailer;
    ...
    move_five_nodes(leader, trailer);
    ...
}
```

I think that the rvalues memory addreses inside the `leader` and `trailer` pointer variables will be assigned into the `Node*` lvalues `ptr1` and `ptr2`.

```
Node* ptr1 = leader;
Node* ptr2 = trailer;
```

The issue is that `ptr1` and `ptr2` are independent local variables inside the function. Initially, they point to the same place as the actual argument pointers. However, my function moves some nodes, and at the end of the function, the values of `ptr1` and `ptr2` are changed. I want these changes to also be in the original variables `leader` and `trailer`, just like references. So even when `ptr1` and `ptr2` expire, `leader` and `trailer` should go into their positions.

How would I do this? Maybe type cast the pointers into `int&`? Or maybe use pointers to pointers? I want to pass a pointer by reference, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to redesign your function `move_five_nodes`. It's a little hard to tell, however. Pointers to pointers would probably work just fine. I don't understand what the issue is to using those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to pass a pointer by reference, but I'm not sure how to do that.

For this, consider the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>

void test(int*& t)
{
    t = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int* i = new int(4);

    test(i);

    if (i == nullptr)
        std::cout << "I was passed by reference" << std::endl;
}
```

in which is is passed by reference to test, where it is set to nullptr and the program prints: `I was passed by reference`.

I think this example should make clear how to pass a pointer by reference to a function.

So in your case the function signiture must change to

```
void LinkedList::move_five_nodes(Node*& ptr1, Node*& ptr2) { ... }
```

Comment: One more question: `int* i = new int[4];` creates a new dynamic array of 4 `ints` and assigns the pointer to `i`, while `int* i = new int(4);` creates a single dynamic integer initialized with `4`, and assigns the pointer to `i`. Am I right? Do I understand this one correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. Was just an example to get a pointer.

Comment: Also nice pun `i was passed by reference`.

Comment: @Galaxy Wasn't intended, but i agrees ;)

Comment: Probably better with delete t; before t = nullptr to avoid a memory-leak..

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
void test(int& ref);
int main()
{
    int* pointer = new int(10);               
    std::cout << "before" << *pointer << std::endl ;
    test(*pointer);
    std::cout << "after" << *pointer << std::endl;
    delete pointer;
}

void test(int& ref)
{    
    ref = 20;
}
```