# Sequence of a pointer reference type

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

[How to pass a pointer variable as a reference parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52349745/10982941)

I have an additional question about this question.

The answerer in the question is using `int*&` as the parameter data type, but I don't understand the sequence of the pointer and reference data type.

In my opinion, `int&*` looks more practical to me, so I tried to compile with that, but it wasn't allowed.

I wanna understand clearly about this logic.

I thought `int*& a` like `int*(int& a)`, so it's like a pointer of a reference, but apparently, it was just right the opposite.

Why can't I use `int&*` as the meaning of a reference of a pointer?

Comment: Read from right to left: `int*&` is a reference to a pointer to int. `int&*` would be a pointer to a reference to int (which is illegal and explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632762/why-are-pointers-to-a-reference-illegal-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ types are name-centered.  `int*&foo` is how you should think of it.

First, we have `&foo` -- `foo` is a reference.  A reference to what?  `*&foo` -- a pointer.  A pointer to what?  `int*&foo` an integer.

The original C type rules where even intended to "demonstrate how they are used".  So `int *foo` is short hand for `int = *foo` being a valid expression, or `*foo` makes an `int`.  The `&` doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: Oh~ thanks!! I totally get it! I just didn't know how to read right

Comment: Typo: "how you shoukd think" should be "how you should think".

Answer (score 2):

[Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

> There are three simple steps to follow:
>
> 1. Starting with the unknown element, move in a spiral/clockwise direction; when ecountering the following elements replace them with
>      the corresponding english statements: [X] or []
>      => Array X size of... or Array undefined size of... (type1, type2)
>      => function passing type1 and type2 returning...
>      *
>      => pointer(s) to...
> 2. Keep doing this in a spiral/clockwise direction until all tokens have been covered.
> 3. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first!

```
               +---------+  
               | +-----+ |
               | | +-+ | |
               | | ^ | | |
           int * & t ; | |
            ^  ^ ^   | | |
            |  | +---+ | |
            |  +-------+ |
            +------------+
```

Stating from `t`, so:

**t is ...**

Then we see `;`, thus keep going and see `&`, so

**t is a reference to ...**

Then we see `*`

**t is a reference to a pointer to ...**

Then we see `int`:

**t is a reference to a pointer to an `int`**

That makes perfect sense. Now let's try the other one:

```
               +---------+  
               | +-----+ |
               | | +-+ | |
               | | ^ | | |
           int & * t ; | |
            ^  ^ ^   | | |
            |  | +---+ | |
            |  +-------+ |
            +------------+
```

Stating from `t`, so:

**t is ...**

Then we see `;`, thus keep going and see `*`, so

**t is a pointer to ...**

Then we see `&`

**t is a pointer to a reference to ...**

Here we immediately run into a problem. You can't have a pointer to a reference. References don't have addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Because `int&*` doesn't really make sense, considering what the notation means.

- `int`: a data type
- `x *`: a pointer to data type `x`
- `x &`: a reference to data type `x`

We can combine them in the following common forms:

- `int *`: a pointer to an int
- `int &`: a reference to an int

I will pause to say that hopefully you know [the difference between passing by reference and by pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-by-pointer-vs-passing-by-reference-in-c/). If not, see the link.

However, we have another combination we can try:

- `int *&`: a reference to a pointer to an int.

We can use a `int *&` like this:
in caller:

```
int * myInt= 0;
myfunction(myInt);
```

in myFunction(int *& myInt):

```
int i;
myInt = &i;
```

myInt int in the caller will be the address of i

> NOTE: setting myInt to the address of a local variable is not a good idea, as the minute `myFunction()` ends, the data stored there will be destroyed. This is just for example purposes only

Finally, there is the question at hand: `int&*`

- `int &*`: a pointer to a reference to an int

Now, I propose this question to you: If we have a reference to an int, why would we need a pointer? Answer: we don't. It doesn't make sense to.

So, in short: `int*&` and `int&*` are two different things. The first makes sense if you break it down, the second one doesn't.